# My batis and spring integration

Tags: spring-mybatis

I am trying to source values from 2 different tables using mybatis and spring batch. I tried writing a composite item reader, with readers for each query but I am not able to successfully configure. Is this implementation correct or are there any better approaches?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I created a new dataset for the second table and used it in the ItemProcessor via .beforeStep(StepExecution).